# Boiling point of oxygen

Tags: physical-chemistry, erratum

I am studying chemistry from the book titled "*Fundamental Chemistry for Cambridge O Level*" written by Rosemarie Gallagher and Paul Ingram. 
On page 17, it states that

> oxygen boils at −219 °C and freezes at −183 °C.

Isn't this incorrect? Should it not be the other way round?

Comment: Yeah that looks like they have it mixed around. The boiling point will always be higher than the melting point measured at the same pressure. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_oxygen) gives the same values, but in the correct order.

Comment: BTW, write (or have your instructor write) to the publisher, citing the error. You might get a "freebie" (e.g. a copy of the next edition, with corrections) and the satisfaction of being acknowledged, as well as performing a service for those who would otherwise have to "unlearn" the error.

Comment: I tried to find some sort of errata for the book and couldn't. According to [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Fundamental-Chemistry-Cambridge-Rosemarie-Gallagher/dp/0198408714) the paperback  was published January 1, 2018 so it isn't an old book.

Answer (score 7):

According to [NIST Chemistry Webbook](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7782447&Mask=4), for oxygen:

$$T_\mathrm{boil} = \pu{90.2\pm0.2 K}$$
$$T_\mathrm{fus} = \pu{54.8\pm0.2 K}$$
$$T_\mathrm{triple} = \pu{54.33\pm0.6 K}$$

The $T_\mathrm{boil}$ and $T_\mathrm{fus}$ are from Ref.1 while Brower and Thodos reported $T_\mathrm{triple}$ as $\pu{54.363 K}$ at pressure of $\pu{1.125 mmHg}$ (Ref.2). The uncertainties were given by Thermodynamics Research Center, *NIST* Boulder Laboratories, CO.

Accordingly, $T_\mathrm{boil} = \pu{-183 ^\circ C}$, $T_\mathrm{fus} = \pu{-218.4 ^\circ C}$, and $T_\mathrm{triple} = \pu{-218.8 ^\circ C}$. Therefore, as you correctly suspected, the values in the textbook is a misprint.

**References:**

1. Alex G. Streng, “Miscibility and compatibility of some liquefied and solidified gases at low temperatures,” *J. Chem. Eng. Data* **1971**, *16(3)*, 357-359 (https://doi.org/10.1021/je60050a024).
2. Gerald T. Brower, George. Thodos, “Vapor pressures of liquid oxygen between the triple point and critical point,” *J. Chem. Eng. Data* **1968**, *13(2)*, 262-264 (https://doi.org/10.1021/je60037a038).